# PHP preg_replace supplement link URL pattern

Tags: preg-replace, explode

I have the following URLs structure:

```
http://example.com/item/example-descriptions/6454986
http://example.com/item/example-bla-bla-bla/6545455
http://example.com/item/example-other-url/5454555
```

I need to add text to the numbers to get so (add "/demo/" and "?id=test")

```
http://example.com/item/example-descriptions/demo/6454986?id=test
http://example.com/item/example-bla-bla-bla/demo/6545455?id=test
http://example.com/item/example-other-url/demo/5454555?id=test
```

Here are a couple of ways imperfect:

```
$myurl = 'http://example.com/item/example-descriptions/6454986';

    if (substr_count($myurl, 'example.com')){
    $url = "$myurl.html";   
    $url = preg_replace('/^(.*)\/([^.]+)\.html$/','$1/demo/$2?id=test', $url); 

    echo "$url";
    } else {  
    echo "$myurl";
}
```

and

```
$myurl = 'http://example.com/item/example-descriptions/6454986';

    if (substr_count($myurl, 'example.com')){
        $url = explode('/', $myurl);  

echo "" . $url[0] . "/" . $url[1] . "/" . $url[2] . "/" . $url[3] . "/" . $url[4] . "/demo/" . $url[5] . "/?id=test";

    } else {  
    echo "$myurl";
}
```

Help me improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
if (parse_url($myurl, PHP_URL_HOST) == 'example.com') {
    $arr = explode('/', $myurl);
    $arr[] = 'demo/' . array_pop($arr) . '?id=test';
    $myurl = implode('/', $arr);
}
```